# How do I add the numeric values to a pack circles plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bubble-chart

I used the following code to plot a packing circle graph and I want to add the numbers (values) for each bubble in addition to the text. How do I do that?
Another question is whether someone knows how to deal with a large number of categories (about 200) which makes some of the plot unreadable. Is there another visualization that might be more useful in this case?

Thanks in advance!

````
library(packcircles)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
library(ggiraph)
packing <- circleProgressiveLayout(data$Number, sizetype='area') 
data <- cbind(data, packing) 
dat.gg <- circleLayoutVertices(packing, npoints=50) 
ggplot() + 
    geom_polygon(data = dat.gg, aes(x, y, fill=as.factor(id), colour = "black", alpha = 0.6)) +
  geom_text(data = data, aes(x, y, size=Number, label = Journal)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(2,4)) +
  theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  coord_equal()```
````

Comment: please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to work with

Comment: '''packing <- circleProgressiveLayout(data$Number, sizetype='area')
data <- cbind(data, packing)
dat.gg <- circleLayoutVertices(packing, npoints=50)
ggplot() + 
   geom_polygon(data = dat.gg, aes(x, y, fill=as.factor(id), colour = "black", alpha = 0.6)) +
    geom_text(data = data, aes(x, y, size=Number, label = Journal)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(2,4)) +
  theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  coord_equal()```

Comment: Hi - i'm not sure how to produce a date set that would fit similar to my data but I hope this help (see above)

Comment: just edit your question including the library you use to run the code and the output of `dput(data)`

Comment: done (without the data)